# Filezilla program not opening after download

Tags: filezilla

I installed Filezilla and on completing the download it gives an option to open. I clicked on that but it doesn't do any action. I cant even find the program anywhere on my system just the setup, which if i run again doesn't make any difference. How can I open Filezilla now?

Comment: Does it mean, that you've correctly installed Filezilla, but can't run it? Or you can't run something downloaded by Filezilla?

Comment: I've installed it correctly, but it isn't opening. Also since this isn't working then what other ftp clients can I use?

Comment: It is simplier to find way to run Filezilla than to install something else and find way to run it.

Comment: I have only downloaded the client. Do I need to download the server too?

Comment: After downloading of the client you have to install it. Also it is better to discuss such question on http://superuser.com/ (since stackoverflow.com is about programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe filezilla installs by default to this directory if using windows:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\FileZilla FTP Client

If you are using win8.1 you can try pointing to the right upper hand corner of your screen and then selecting the search pane and type in "Filezilla" to find it's location.  You can also go to "control panel" select "programs and features" sort by "installed on" and see if it installed on your computer.  If it did, you might want to uninstall from there, delete the setup file and then try it again from the beginning in case something went wrong during the install.

Comment: Didn't help. Anything else?

Comment: When you checked in control panel/programs and features, did it show that filezilla was installed?

Comment: Can't see the folder programs and features. I am using windows 7

Comment: If you aren't in classic view, it will show up as simply "programs" I believe (it has been a while since I looked at win7).  Once you click programs, you should see programs and features.  Or you can switch from category view to classic view (all control panel items) and then it will show up as programs and features.  Click that. You can sort by install date or file name and see if filezilla is showing up as installed.

Comment: I am in classic view only. can't see any folder with programs or features

Comment: It should be there.  Here is a link to microsoft's page on the subject:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uninstall-change-program#uninstall-change-program=windows-7

Comment: Actually I'm not signing in through the admin but a different user. Could that be the reason I can't see the programs folder in Control Panel?

Comment: I've been through the pages on Filezilla and I feel i cant set up the program because of administrator restrictions. Could that be possible?

Comment: Yes, to both questions.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I just started an administrative command prompt and ran the executable with /x and it ran (no idea if /x matters at all, I usually use that to extract archived installers)

In this case it just ran the install, which wouldn't run from explorer.